# Perform an operation on same thread within a Parallel Execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a requirement, such that I need to do some synchronous processing within a parallel execution flow.

I have some tasks working within a Parallel foreach. Now what I need to do is that, in between do some database updates.
Which I do not want to be done using async and await, since this would invoke multiple threads and loading my server.

Since these database updates are important for me, but I do not want them to block my main flow of execution.
What I want to achieve is that the database updates should always be done on the same thread synchronously, which would fasten the main flow.

Is this possible while I use a Task? If so, can anyone please suggest on the same.

Comment: If you want them done synchronously, just run them synchronously. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you post some sample code? At the moment it is unclear what your are trying to do and what the problem is.

Comment: `async`/`await` does not imply multiple threads. You can easily use asynchronous DB access within an `ActionBlock<T>` (see dcastro's answer), and it will only do one save at a time (asynchronously).

Comment: Luaan: Thanks for your reply. Basically the problem is that the each time, this will be called for parallel execution, it would generate new threads. This is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you have several concurrent tasks wanting to save something to do the database - but the db access has to be single-threaded, and not concurrent, correct?

You also don't want the concurrent tasks to block while data is being saved to the database.

If so, use a TPL Dataflow [`ActionBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(n => SaveIntToDatabase(n));
```

And then have your concurrent tasks post stuff to the block:

```
actionBlock.Post(2);       //blocking
actionBlock.SendAsync(2);  //non-blocking
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response. Actually its different. I will be updating database in multiple threads as well. But the point is, that there is one separate process which I need to do for say "Health Monitoring" where I need to update values in database, which should not hamper/affect the main flow of the code. Hope its clear now?